How do I organize my .bib file to print a index grouped and sorted by authors and series?
I am generating several volumes whose content is in a database, so I am free to generate with relative ease the content of the .bib file where the references will be stored and the content of .tex files for place the citations.
I would like to know what would be the best way to organize my .bib file to obtain an index similar to this:

If we take the example of Agustin, san, I have created these @collection entries:
@collection{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos,
    editor       = {Agustín, san},
    title        = {Comentarios sobre los Salmos}
}

@collection{AgustinSermones,
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Sermones},
}

@collection{AgustinSermonGuelferbitano,
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Sermón Güelferbitano},
}

@collection{AgustinSermonMai98,
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Sermón Mai 98},
}

@collection{AgustinTratadoSanJuan,
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Tratados sobre el evangelio de san Juan},
}

And I have also created these @incollection entries to relate to their respective collection:
@incollection{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos:Salmo-060-002003,
    crossref = {AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Salmo 60, 2-3.}

}

@incollection{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos:Salmo-1,
    crossref = {AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Salmo 61, 3-4.}
}

@incollection{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos:Salmo-62,
    crossref = {AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Salmo 62, 3-4.}
}

@incollection{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos:Salmo-060-002003,
    crossref = {AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Salmo 60, 2-3.}
}

@incollection{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos:Salmo-061-004,
    crossref = {AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Salmo 61, 4.}
}

@incollection{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos:Salmo-085-001,
    crossref = {AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Salmo 85, 1.}
}

@incollection{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos:Salmo-140-004006,
    crossref = {AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Salmo 140, 4-6.}
}

@incollection{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos:Salmo-148-001002,
    crossref = {AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Salmo 148, 1-2.}
}

@incollection{AgustinSermones:Sermon-0008-0104,
    crossref = {AgustinSermones},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Sermón 8, En la octava de Pascua 1, 4.}
}

@incollection{AgustinSermones:Sermon-0034-01030506,
    crossref = {AgustinSermones},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Serm. 34, 1-3. 5-6.}
}

@incollection{AgustinSermones:Sermon-0096-010409,
    crossref = {AgustinSermones},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Serm. 96, 1. 4. 9.}
}

@incollection{AgustinSermonGuelferbitano:Sermon-003,
    crossref = {AgustinSermonGuelferbitano},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Sermón Güelferbitano 3.}
}

@incollection{AgustinSermonMai98:001-002,
    crossref = {AgustinSermonMai98},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Serm. Mai 98: Sobre la Ascensión del Señor, 1-2.}
}

@incollection{AgustinTratadoSanJuan:0015-010012016017,
    crossref = {AgustinTratadoSanJuan},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Tratado 15, 10-12. 16-17.}
}

@incollection{AgustinTratadoSanJuan:0034-008009,
    crossref = {AgustinTratadoSanJuan},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Tratado 34, 8-9.}
}

@incollection{AgustinTratadoSanJuan:0065-001003,
    crossref = {AgustinTratadoSanJuan},
    author    = {Agustín, san},
    title = {Tratado 65, 1-3.}
}

With this EMV, trying to follow the Example 22 of biblatex:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[indexing=cite,style=authortitle,autolang=hyphen,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[columns=1]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\makeindex[options=-s dotted, name=name-title,title={Name and Title Index}]

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{biblatex_legacy}
  {\DeclareIndexNameFormat{name:title}{%
     \iffieldundef{title}
       {\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[name-title]}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{index:name:title}{\index[name-title]}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}}
  {\DeclareIndexNameFormat{name:title}{%
     \iffieldundef{title}
       {\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[name-title]}
          {\namepartfamily}
          {\namepartgiven}
          {\namepartprefix}
          {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{index:name:title}{\index[name-title]}
          {\namepartfamily}
          {\namepartgiven}
          {\namepartprefix}
          {\namepartsuffix}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{with:year}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {\usebibmacro{index:entry}{\index[year-title]}{%
       \mkbibindexentry{0}{Not dated}%
       \subentryoperator%
       \mkbibindexfield{\thefield{indexsorttitle}}{\emph{#1}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{index:entry}{\index[year-title]}{%
       \thefield{year}\subentryoperator%
       \mkbibindexfield{\thefield{indexsorttitle}}{\emph{#1}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames[name:title]{labelname}%
     \indexfield[with:year]{indextitle}}
    {}}
    
\begin{document}

    \cite{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos:Salmo-060-002003}
    \cite{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos:Salmo-061-004}
    \newpage
    \cite{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos:Salmo-085-001}
    \cite{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos:Salmo-140-004006}
    \cite{AgustinComentariosSobreLosSalmos:Salmo-148-001002}
    \newpage
    \cite{AgustinSermones:Sermon-0008-0104}
    \cite{AgustinSermones:Sermon-0034-01030506}
    \cite{AgustinSermones:Sermon-0096-010409}
    \cite{AgustinSermonGuelferbitano:Sermon-003}
    \newpage
    \cite{AgustinSermonMai98:001-002}
    \cite{AgustinTratadoSanJuan:0015-010012016017}
    \cite{AgustinTratadoSanJuan:0034-008009}
    \newpage
    \cite{AgustinTratadoSanJuan:0065-001003} 

    \clearpage
    \printindex[name-title] 
\end{document}

I get the following result:

Basically, I would need:

Group/sort by author: Agustín, san
Group/sort by each author's entry

The idea is to obtain a result similar to the one that appears in the first screenshot shown at the beginning of the question.
How could I achieve this?

To me, the required output looks more like an index than a bibliography. Have you looked at how to generate an index?

Is this what you want maybe? Biblatex supports \entrysetpunct command too (see parag. 4.10.1 in biblatex manual).

Example 22 from the official BibLaTeX documentation on https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples seems highly relevant.
